# OpenGL ES GLSL shader on Android not loading correct version?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, glsles

I'm following this example on rendering the camera preview using GLES 2.0 (http://maninara.blogspot.com/2012/09/render-camera-preview-using-opengl-es.html). It worked great until I copied some GLSL shader code from somewhere else and noticed it didn't work and I get this error:

```
error C7502: OpenGL does not allow type suffix 'f' on constant literals in versions below 120
```

So to see if the problem was from my copied shader code, I changed this line in the vertex shader example (see link above) from

```
gl_Position = vec4 ( vPosition.x, vPosition.y, 0.0, 1.0 )
```

to

```
gl_Position = vec4 ( vPosition.x, vPosition.y, 0.0f, 1.0f )
```

but I still get the same error. I've confirmed GLSL's version is high enough by outputting GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) which gives:

```
GLSL Version = OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
```

Am I setting up my OpenGL ES context incorrectly? What's going on here?

UPDATE: If I add "#version 120", I get this error:

```
error C0201: unsupported version 120
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why did you *add* the `f` suffix when the compiler did tell you that it is *not* supported? These suffixes actually do not mean anything in GLSL, and literals are single precision by default anyway - there is the `lf` suffix for double precision.

It seems like there is some `f` suffix somewhere else in that shader, and it won't compile until that is removed.

> I've confirmed GLSL's version is high enough by outputting > GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) which gives:
>
> > GLSL Version = OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10

That just says that the implementation is supporting up to GLSL ES 3.10, not that you are *using* it. If you have no `#version` directive in your shader sources, the default `#version 100 ES` will be used.

Comment: The copied shader code was using "f" as a suffix and did not use #version to indicate a certain shader version and the app I copied from doesn't give this error.....

Comment: That doesn't change what I said. The compiler is right about this error. What the other app does it completely unkown. There are many different ways it could achieve that result, but it is useless to speculate.

Comment: @t2k32316: `#version 120 ES` _doesn't exist_.

Comment: sorry, I meant to write #version 120. Still same error.

Comment: @t2k32316: `#version 120` is for _desktop_ GL, not GLES. In GLES there is only 100, 300 and 310.

Comment: @t2k32316: But since you are using `GLES2`, I wonder why you don't stick to `100 ES` as this is the only one guaranteed to be available for GLES2. Just remove those unnecessary suffixes.

Comment: To be precise, the `f` suffix is not allowed in ES 2.0 (`100 es` shader version), and is legal in the GLSL versions that go with ES 3.0 and later. Even though the compilers of some vendors also silently accept it with ES 2.0.